# Count ways to reach the 4th stair using step 1, 2 or 3

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 46;
        int [] arr = new int[n];
        arr[1]=1;
        arr[2]= 2;
        arr[3]=4;
        for(int i=3;i<n;i++){
            arr[i]= arr[i-1]+arr[i-2]+arr[i-3];
        }
        System.out.println(arr[3]);
    }
```

> My output is coming as 6 , but in real it should be 7.

```
arr[1] = 1 way.
arr[2] = 1,1 or 2 
arr[3] = 1,1,1 ; 2,1 ; 1,2 ; 3
```

> **so in total the answer should be 7, where i am getting wrong??**

Comment: because when for i=3 is running it is adding arr[2]+arr[1]+arr[0] and you have not defined arr[0]  so it is updating arr[3] as 3. when it is going for arr[4]=3+2+1 =6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop starts with `i = 3`, but you already filled in `res[3]`. That is not a problem if the number of ways to reach `3` would be the same as in your hardcoded value `arr[3] = 4;`, but it is *not*.

Indeed, you never have set `res[0]` to `1`, and therefore, it will calculate `res[3] = res[2] + res[1] + res[0]` as `3`, not `4`.

You furthermore returned `res[3]` instead of `res[n]`, and you should initialize an array of length `n+1`.

The smallest fix is thus to set `res[0]` to `1` as well:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 46;
    int [] arr = new int[n+1];
    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 1;
    arr[2] = 2;
    arr[3] = 4;
    for(int i = 3; i < n; i++){
        arr[i]= arr[i-1]+arr[i-2]+arr[i-3];
    }
    System.out.println(arr[n]);
}
```